# If $R = \{(1,2),(1,4),(3,3),(4,1)\}$, then is $(1,2) \in R^2$? (Powers of Relation)

Tags: recurrence-relations, solution-verification, relations

I basically got this:

$R^2 =\{(4,4),(1,1),(3,3),(4,2)\}$

But I'm not sure if I should include (1,2) as well since 2 maps to nothing?

Thanks

Comment: No, $(1,2)$ is not in $R^2$ but it is in $R\cup (R^2)$.  Your calculation of $R^2$ is correct.

Comment: If you need some way to cement your intuition, imagine a game board with four positions which are labeled $1,2,3,4$ with paths leading between positions which travel in a specific direction similar to chutes and ladders if that pair of numbers appear in your relation.  (*More formally, consider a directed multigraph with directed edgeset equal to your relation*).  The relation $R$ describes the available moves from one position to another which travel along a single path to get to their destination.  $R^2$ describes those which require the use of exactly two movements along paths.

Comment: There is indeed no way to start at $1$ and take exactly two movements to get to $2$ using the available directed edges.  You could do it in exactly one movement or in exactly three or exactly five, etc... but not in $2$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks. I checked the definition and it was "if $(x,y) \in R1 \wedge (y,z) \in R2 then (x,z) \in R2 o R1$ for compositions, in this case, since the premise is false, wouldn't that make the conditional statement true, therefore (x,z) is in the composition? I'm thinking in terms of transitivity, since (1,2) would count as transitive.

edit: just saw your new comments, will read through them now

Comment: The definition should be "If *there exists some* $y$ where $\langle x,y\rangle\in R_1\wedge\langle y,z\rangle \in R_2$, then *and only then* $\langle x,z\rangle\in R_2\circ R_1$" The definition is an *equivalence*, not a mere implication. $$R_2\circ R_1=\{\langle x,z\rangle: \exists y~.(\langle x,y\rangle \in R_1\wedge\langle y,z\rangle\in R_2)\}$$

Comment: " in this case, since the premise is false, wouldn't that make the conditional statement true"  Ouch. Not quite.  If the premise is false then *definition* (the conditional statement) is true, but the *conclusion*'s truth is unknown. The way a definition of the form, "if conditions are met, then terminology" works is that the $CONDITIONS\implies TERM$ is always true. So when conditions hold, the definition term is true. If conditions don't hold...it's implied the term isnt true but technically it's unknown. Technically definitions should be if and only if statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather, $R$ maps $1$ to $2$, and maps $1$ to $4$, but does not map *either* $2$ or $4$ *to* $2$, so $R^2$ does not map $1$ to $2$.

$$\big(\neg\exists y~.(\langle 1,y\rangle\in R\wedge\langle y,2\rangle\in R)\big)~\to~ \langle 1,2\rangle\notin R^2$$

---

$${R^2 =\{\langle x, z\rangle: \exists y~.(\langle x,y\rangle\in R\wedge\langle y,z\rangle\in R)\}\\\quad=\{\langle 1,1\rangle, \langle 3,3 \rangle, \langle 4,2 \rangle, \langle 4, 4\rangle\}}$$